# Protractor Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token =

Tags: selenium, protractor

I have an impression that my scripts for webdriver suddenly stopped working.
This was working for me before:

```
var loginPageObject = require ('./pageObjects/00_login_page.po.js');

describe('log in to app', function() {

  it('should login to app', function() {

browser.get('https://myapp/#!/login');
element(by.name('email')).sendKeys('user');
element(by.name('password')).sendKeys('pwd');;
element(by.name('formLogin')).submit();
expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual('https://myapp/#!/dashboard');

  });

});
```

And now it returns **Unexpected token =**

```
[launcher] Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\myapp\src\ui\test\e2e\login_to_app.js:1:9)
```

login_to_app.js:1:9 is by the "=require". The file login_to_app.js exists.

Because when I change name of the file in the require command, for example

```
var a = require ('./pageObjects/00_login_page.po.js.BLAH');
describe('log in to app', function() {
    it('should login to app', function()
```

It returns error

```
[launcher] Error: Error: Cannot find module './pageObjects/00_login_page.po.js.BLAH'
```

Any ideas? I have another projects where very similar scripts work with var a = require ('./pageObjects/00_login_page.po.js');

This is my **pageObjects/00_login_page.po.js**

```
var LoginPage = function () {

var user        = 'myuser';
var pwd         = 'mypwd';
var loginForm   = element(by.name('formLogin'));    
var username    = element(by.name('email'));
var password    = element(by.name('password'));
var register    = = element(By.xpath('/html/body/div/div/main/section/p[1]/a'));

this.getLoginPage = function () {browser.get('myapp/#!/login');};
this.setUsername = function (name) {username.sendKeys(name);};
this.setPassword = function (_password) {password.sendKeys(_password);};
this.enterUsername = function () {this.setUsername(user);};
this.enterPassword = function () {this.setPassword(pwd);};
this.loginFormSubmit = function () {loginForm.submit();}

};

module.exports = LoginPage;
```

Comment: Could you show what is inside `00_login_page.po.js`?

Comment: Hi @alexce I have pasted 00_login_page.po.js into my first question.

Comment: oh man... there are double "= =" at var register    = = element(By.xpath('/html/body/div/div/main/section/p[1]/a')); I was just searching not in this file. Thanks @alexce for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

This is due to project dependencies versions and also npm/node versions. I had this error when running tests after downgrading to node 4.1.1. I had to sync dependencies for protractor and selenium-webdriver.

"protractor": "2.5.1",
"selenium-webdriver": "3.0.0-beta-3",

these 2 versions work with npm/node versions v3.3.5/v4.1.1